# Por que os valores de x e v[0] não são iguais? - linguagem C

Tags: c, ponteiro

Estou revendo alguns conceitos no site : [Endereços e Ponteiros](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/pont.html), até que encontro o seguinte código:

```
void func1 (int x) {
   x = 9 * x;
}

void func2 (int v[]) {
   v[0] = 9 * v[0];
}

int main (void) {
   int x, v[2];
   x    = 111; 
   func1 (x); printf ("x: %d\n", x);
   v[0] = 111; 
   func2 (v); printf ("v[0]: %d\n", v[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/DNrBBY)

Para minha surpresa a saída foi:

```
x: 111
v[0]: 999
```

Minha dúvida:

Por que x e V[0] não são iguais? Já que possuem o mesmo valor (`111`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa tarde Luiz,

Isso ocorre porque na função `func1 (int x)` você está passando o valor de x, e não a referência de x, portanto as alterações do valor do mesmo são feitas apenas dentro da função.

Se você jogar um `printf()` dentro da `funct1` você verá que vai dar 999.

isso não ocorre no caso da `funct2` pois, por se tratar de um vetor, o valor de `v`(sem referência) já é o próprio endereço de memória do elemento 0 do vetor.

Um exemplo disso é quando vamos trabalhar com strings em C, não se usa o `&` no `scanf()` pois a variável já guarda o endereço do primeiro elemento.

**Solução:**

Caso você queira manter o mesmo formato da função, isto é, não quiser passar como parâmetro um ponteiro pra alterar o valor de x, você pode modificar seu código pra x receber o resultado da função

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func1 (int x) {

   x = x * 9;    
}

void func2 (int v[]) {
   v[0] = 9 * v[0];
}

 int main (void) {

  int x, v[2];

  x = 111; 
  x = func1 (x);
  printf ("x: %d\n", x);

  v[0] = 111; 
  func2 (v); 
  printf ("v[0]: %d\n", v[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Já no caso de você quiser alterar a função para passar `x` como parâmetro, ficará assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func1 (int *x) {

  *x = *x * 9;

}

void func2 (int v[]) {

    v[0] = 9 * v[0];
}

int main (void) {
int x = 111, v[2];

func1 (&x);
printf ("x: %d\n", x);

v[0] = 111; 
func2 (v); 
printf ("v[0]: %d\n", v[0]);

return 0;
}
```

Onde `*x` se refere ao conteúdo da variável `x`.

Não sei se ficou claro, mas irei editar a resposta caso reste alguma dúvida.

Espero ter ajudado,

Abraços!

Comment: Caso queira edite sua pergunta adicionando o pedaço do código onde x passe por parâmetro e não valor.

Comment: No mesmo segundo em que enviei você editou, boa!

Comment: Boa tarde H. Lima!! perfeita a resposta, clareou bastante as coisas aqui! muito obrigado!!

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar! boa sorte nos estudos :D